# Custom heapify function based on iterators

Tags: c++, heap

I'm trying to make a custom (and not use the STL one) heap sort method that works on my custom containers. I have iterators, however I can't find a description of the make_heap algorithm. As far as I understood, it does something like arranging the elements so they look like a binary heap where each parent node has its two children right next to it, however what about the children's children? How exactly is it arranged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of elements after a call to `std::make_heap` is implementation-defined. The only thing that's specified is that the biggest element is placed first in the range.

I believe that in the most common implementation, if a node is stored at index `i`, then its left child is stored at `2*i+1` and its right child at `2*i+2`.

Comment: It seems to be way harder to make with iterators, most algorithms are based on a recursive function with indices. I think that if I can make an iterator-based GetLeftChild, GetRightChild and GetParent, the rest would be straightforward. But multiplying an iterator won't give me anything sensible. Could you suggest a similar operation for an iterator?

Comment: What do you mean? Why can't you just do `std::make_heap(b, e)` where `b` is an iterator to the beginning of the range and `e` to the end?

Comment: @shortage_radeon For RandomAccessIterators, you can subtract them (or use `std::distance`) and add integers to them, much like you can use pointers.